# How to create custom view with on Click in android

Tags: android

This is my class

```
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.View
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
import timber.log.Timber


class ContactUsLink : AppCompatTextView, View.OnClickListener {
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyle) {
        init()
    }

    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) {
        init()
    }

    constructor(context: Context?) : super(context) {
        init()
    }

    private fun init() {
        setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    override fun onLayout(changed: Boolean, left: Int, top: Int, right: Int, bottom: Int) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom)
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
       Timber.d("Click Event ");

        // Do whatever you need to
    }
}
```

This is my XML calling like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="@color/background_grey"
              android:orientation="vertical">

<com.tesco.clubcardmobile.features.common.customview.ContactUsLink
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="Click Here"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I am able to display view in my layout display text view but when I click on the text of text view on click is not working can you please tell me how to apply on click function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance())` on your custom view and it will open browser
The `onClick` method is no longer needed as `LinkMovementMethod` will do all the work for you. Also, you can use `UrlSpannable`.

Here is your updated custom view. It no longer needs `OnClickListener` and `Context` no longer nullable type.

```
import android.content.Context
import android.text.SpannableString
import android.text.Spanned
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod
import android.text.style.URLSpan
import android.util.AttributeSet
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView

class ContactUsLink : AppCompatTextView {
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyle: Int) : super(
        context,
        attrs,
        defStyle
    ) {
        init()
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) {
        init()
    }

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
        init()
    }

    private fun init() {
        val spannableString = SpannableString(text.toString())
        spannableString.setSpan(
            URLSpan("https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/URLSpan?authuser=1"),
            0,
            text.length,
            Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
        )
        text = spannableString
        movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
    }

}
```

And here is your XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_grey"
    android:orientation="vertical">

     
    <com.tesco.clubcardmobile.features.common.customview.ContactUsLink
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:text="Click. Here"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer can you please tell me how to set text i have to set text on Custom view   with XYA

Comment: @ManojKumar added complete code. If it helped - please rate my answer and accept. Will be very grateful.

Comment: it works. I checked it. But you can do the same without a custom view.

Comment: ok its working fine but I want to set text in custom view textvieew.text ="XYA" how i will set

Comment: @ManojKumar updated. just added `UrlSpannable`. is it that you've been looking for?

Comment: i want set text like "hello worl" in text view  like textview.textt = "hello world". in ContactUsLink class val linkTextView = TextView(context)
        linkTextView.text = context?.getString(R.string.call_us_url).  i tried like this in init() method but it not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224243/discussion-between-manoj-kumar-and-nazarii-moshenskiy).

Answer (score 0):

If you want your whole view to be clickable, and not just a URL in a span on the text (which you should avoid when possible, as it may be a small touch target), then

```kotlin
override fun onClick(v: View) {
    val intent = Intent(
        Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
        Uri.parse("https://www.tesco.com/help/contact/")
    )
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

Comment: android:text="Click. Here". i dont want set in XML i want in ContactUsLink class

Comment: @ManojKumar This goes in your `onClick()` handler.